Meaning of ई॒ळे॒ in first verse of Rig Veda
I am quoting Rig Veda 1.1.1

अ॒ग्निमी॑ळे पु॒रोहि॑तं य॒ज्ञस्य॑ दे॒वमृ॒त्विज॑म् । होता॑रं
रत्न॒धात॑मम्

The highlighted word is ई॒ळे॒, whose meaning I cannot able to find in Sanskrit. It seems like even Sayanacharya didn't comment on the meaning of that word. One quora user claimed that ई॒ळे॒ refers to Tamil eelam and when Vedas say Agnimile it means I praise Agni from the east. Now Tamil eelam (Sri Lankan Tamil) isn't located anywhere in the east of north India even if we assume that Vedas are composed in North India. So this interpretation also cannot be correct.
What is the actual meaning of the word ई॒ळे॒?

Iḷe: I laud, says Sayana; I beseech, says Yaska. The other meanings are I adore, I pray. It has nothing to do with Tamil Ilam.
Reference - https://theveda.org.in/rigveda/01/001/1

I’m voting to close this question because this is not a translations forum

The meaning is non-ambiguous.  ई॒ळे॒ is the Atmanepadi first person singular present indicative of the verb  īḍ  = “praise; invite; raise."  Only vedic Sanskrit has the retroflex l sound (present in today's Tamil, Malayalam, Marathi etc.) which became retroflex d in classical Sanskrit.
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc828866.html
The verse means

I glorify Agni, the high priest of the sacrifice, the divine, the ministrant, who presents the oblation (to the gods), and is the possessor of great wealth

https://oursanskrit.com/sanskrit-grammar-reference/pronunciation-of-sanskrit-letters/
explains further:

Note that the retroflexed ळ्  ḷ is used in sanskrit only as a subsititute for ड्  ḍ between vowels [Example īḷe  ईळे for  īḍe ईडे.] There is also an aspirated version of ḷh  ळ्ह् which is substituted for ढ्  ḍh between vowels [Example mīḷhuṣe  मीळ्हुषे for mīḍhuṣe  मीढुषे]


So it is not a Tamil word.

Not according to Mayrhofer’s Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Altindoarischen (‘Etymological Dictionary of Indo-Iranian’), no. He compares it to Greek αἴδομαι aídomai ‘honour, respect’ and Gothic aistan ‘hold back, respect’, from Proto-Indo-European *h₂ei̯sd-, an extension of the root *h₂ei̯s- (found in German Ehre ‘honour’, Skt. इच्छति icchati ‘search’, etc.). Ved. ईड् īḍ- would be from a (probably reduplicated) zero-grade, *(h₂i-)h₂isd-. Not the most bulletproof etymology, but reasonable enough.

the retroflex sound suggests It could be from Tamil ஈடு īṭu - one of the meanings is  reward, compensation,  But this is only a guess. @tattvamasi

But here the word is used to praise not reward

Sometimes, words change meaning when one language borrows it from another language.  This just a guess - I'll research some more. @tattvamasi

@SK There is a city called Varna in Bulgaria. Comparing completely different meanings of words from different languages is like saying Varna system originated there
